# Создание и оперирование динамическим массивом из функции, а также scanf [СИ]

Tags: c, функции, динамические-массивы, динамические-структуры, scanf

Добpый вeчep!

Цель: создать и заполнить дин. массив в main из функции

Проблема: Не выделяется место (где-то начудил с * и &) и scanf выдает ошибку

Предисловие: 3й раз создаю уже тему, никто не может нормально описать, где и что не так. И да - я знаю, что так делать нехорошо и функция должна взаимодействовать с main только через return. И еще - это кусок кода (где убрана ерись, чтоб вам легче было разобраться)

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Структура, являющаяся элементами массива
struct token {
 unsigned int postindex;
 unsigned long long int bedeutung;
}

int main() {
 // Переменные
 struct token *token_dynmass;

 // Функция
 InputFiller(&token_dynmass);

 return 0;
}

char InputFiller(struct token **token_dynmass) {

 // Инициализация структуры
 *token_dynmass = (struct token*)malloc(4*sizeof(struct token));
 *token_dynmass = (struct token*)realloc((*token_dynmass),(4*1.5*sizeof(struct token)));

 // Считываем индекс (ключ)
 scanf("%llu", &(token_dynmass[0]->bedeutung));
 }
```

Послесловие:
Нужно сделать так, чтоб после в main я мог прописать команды for и printf и вывести этот массив.

Ошибка:
Access Violation...

Вот ссылка на весь код: https://pastebin.com/jeDPwbYy

Cпacибо!